# Problem editing html using Window.getSelection() method - Html malformed

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events

I am developing an application that allows highlighting selected texts. I am using `Window.getSelection()` to be able to edit html and highlighting by using mark tags.

The problem appears when trying to highlight text blocks that are included within lists (li tags). When doing this, the html seems to be malformed.

Some screenshots to visualize the problem:

[1.jpg](https://www.imartic.es/imagenes/1.jpg)
[2.jpg](https://www.imartic.es/imagenes/2.jpg)
[3.jpg](https://www.imartic.es/imagenes/3.jpg)
[4.jpg](https://www.imartic.es/imagenes/4.jpg)
[5.jpg](https://www.imartic.es/imagenes/5.jpg)

Here are attached codesnippet too, to reproduce and test the problem.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".div-sombreado").each(function() {
    $(this).mouseup(function(e) {
      var html = FormatearCadenaMarcada(getHTMLOfSelection());
      ActualizarHTML(html);
    });
  });
});

function FormatearCadenaMarcada(html) {

  if (html == "" || html == "undefined" || html == undefined) {
    return "";
  }

  //Eliminamos etiquetas mark que haya dentro de la parte seleccionada
  html = EliminarEtiquetasHtml(html, "mark");
  html = "<mark style=\"background-color: yellow;\">" + html + "</mark>";

  return html;
}

function EliminarEtiquetasHtml(html, tag) {
  var indexTagInicio = 0;
  var indexTagFin = 0;

  indexTagInicio = html.indexOf("<" + tag, 0);

  //Eliminar etiquetas apertura
  while (indexTagInicio >= 0) {
    indexTagFin = html.indexOf(">", indexTagInicio);
    html = [html.slice(0, indexTagInicio), "", html.slice(indexTagFin + (">").length)].join('');

    indexTagInicio = html.indexOf("<" + tag, indexTagInicio);
  }

  indexTagInicio = html.indexOf("</" + tag + ">", 0);

  //Eliminar etiquetas cierre
  while (indexTagInicio >= 0) {
    html = [html.slice(0, indexTagInicio), "", html.slice(indexTagInicio + ("</" + tag + ">").length)].join('');

    indexTagInicio = html.indexOf("</" + tag + ">", indexTagInicio);
  }

  return html;
}

function getHTMLOfSelection() {
  var range;
  if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
    range = document.selection.createRange();
    return range.htmlText;
  } else if (window.getSelection) {
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    if (selection.rangeCount > 0) {
      range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
      var clonedSelection = range.cloneContents();
      var div = document.createElement('div');
      div.appendChild(clonedSelection);
      return div.innerHTML;
    } else {
      return '';
    }
  } else {
    return '';
  }
}

function ActualizarHTML(html) {
  var range;
  if (html != "" && html != "undefined" && html != undefined) {
    if (window.getSelection && window.getSelection().getRangeAt) {
      range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
      range.deleteContents();
      var div = document.createElement("div");
      div.innerHTML = html;
      var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(),
        child;
      while ((child = div.firstChild)) {
        frag.appendChild(child);
      }
      range.insertNode(frag);
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
      range = document.selection.createRange();
      range.pasteHTML(html);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="div-sombreado">
    <ul>
      <li>Elemento uno de la lista</li>
      <li>Elemento dos de la lista</li>
      <li>Elemento tres de la lista</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: How to reproduce this issue? The code seems to work properly.

Comment: @randomSoul by ending the selection in a different row that it started. And watch how the browser tries to fix/interpret the messed up markup.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas , any idea to fix this problem?

Comment: yes, you have to traverse the DOM from the selectionStart to the selectionEnd and wrap each *(relevant)* `#text`-node individually in a `<mark>` tag. so not `<div>lorem <mark>ipsum</div><div>dolor</mark> sit ahmet</div>` but instead `<div>lorem <mark>ipsum</mark></div><div><mark>dolor</mark> sit ahmet</div>`

Answer (score 0):

Finally the solution was to use document.execCommand to highlight selection text and use span tag instead mark tags.

Thanks to everyone!

```js
document.onmouseup = () => {
                sel = window.getSelection();
                if (sel.rangeCount && sel.getRangeAt) {
                    range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
                }
                // Set design mode to on
                document.designMode = "on";
                if (range) {
                    sel.removeAllRanges();
                    sel.addRange(range);
                }
                // Colorize text
                document.execCommand("BackColor", false, "#FF0011");
                // Set design mode to off
                document.designMode = "off";
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>    
        <div class="div-sombreado">
            <ul>
    <li>Elemento uno</li>
    <li>Elemento dos</li>
    <li>Elemento tres</li>
    <li>Elemento cuatro</li>
   </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```